# You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In my app.xaml.cs I create a new page.

```
 public App()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WrapLayoutPage());
  }
```

This page calls a static class, which uses the DependencyService to perform some tasks.

The line which throws the error:

```
var tmpTable = SqLiteHelper.GetItem<TableX>("someId");
```

**SqLiteHelper:**

```
public static class SqLiteHelper
{
    private static readonly SQLiteConnection DatabaseConnection = DependencyService.Get<ISqLite>().GetConnection();
    private static readonly object Locker = new object();

    public static DbObjectV3 GetItem<T>(Guid inId) where T : DbObjectV3, new()
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            var tmpItem = DatabaseConnection.Table<T>().FirstOrDefault(inItem => inItem.Id == inId);
            tmpItem.IsNewObject = false;
            return tmpItem;
        }
    }
}
```

This throws me a `TypeInitializationException` with the InnerException:

> You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it

**It's somehow related to the static helper class, because prior to that call, I can use the DependencyService without any problems!**

As mainlauncher I'm using a splash screen. In this class I do some startup work, which relies on the DependencyService.

**SplashScreen:**

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", NoHistory = true, MainLauncher = true)]
    public class SplashScreen : Activity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashScreen).Name;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
        }
}
```

**My MainActivity:**

```
 [Activity(Label = "FrameworkForms", Icon = "@drawable/icon", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, Theme = "@style/MainActivityTheme", MainLauncher = false)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            App.ScreenWidth = (double)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Now after changing the *Activity* in SplashScreen to *FormsAppCompatActivity*, I get another error.

> Call Forms.Init() before Hide Keyboard

What's the thing here?

Comment: Could you make sure that you have same version of _Xamarin.Forms_ libraries in the Android and Shared project?

Comment: @PrashantC I do. Just upgraded both to newest version (2.3.3.175)

Comment: That's rather strange! Is this a new project? Does it happen with new projects? Could you share the [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output)

Comment: No it's not. I wasn't working on it in a few weeks, but it certainly was running before. I'm trying to reproduce it with a new project.

Comment: @PrashantC Funny thing, it seems like it doesn't have anything to do with DependencyService. If I use another implementation (which checks the internet connection), it works. The problem is related to the static helper class..

Comment: Have you implemented custom Splash screen, if so, you should also init in Forms there also.

Comment: @Kowalski Yes indeed, I have. I also implemented it there, nothing changes..

Comment: Have you tried changing the base class of your `MainActivity` from `FormsApplicationActivity` to `FormsAppCompatActivity`? When I create a new project, the latter is default and both compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: @Demitrian I have. There are multiple other issues with AppCompat and Xamarin.Forms. It's not really suggested.. Without the splash screen and with appcompat it's working. But the splash screen is causing troubles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is pretty unfortunate. I used the wrong `OnCreate()` method in my SplashScreen.

I changed SplashScreen to:

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", NoHistory = true, MainLauncher = true)]
    public class SplashScreen : Activity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashScreen).Name;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
        }


        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            Task tmpStartupWork = new Task(() =>
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
                StartUpTasks.InitializeDatabaseCreation();
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Working in the background - important stuff.");
            });

            tmpStartupWork.ContinueWith(inT =>
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Work is finished - start MainActivity.");
                StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            tmpStartupWork.Start();
        }
    }
```

**Unfortunately, the documentation on Xamarin about creating a splash screen uses the OnCreate() method with 2 parameters!**

Comment: The one without paramaters is the one am using but am exending Application

Comment: Kudos,you saved my time ;)

Comment: save me:   Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this mistake. The cause of the error was that I wanted to change my namespace. From

```
public partial class AppDelegate : 
       global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
```

I changed it to:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
public partial class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
```

Then I saw the following:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
```

I thought, it would be useful to adjust that as well... without thinking more exactly about it. And I wrote:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    this.Init();
```

A while later, I got the mistake and had to laboriously search for the cause. Finally I found and fixed it. Maybe it can help someone :-) Cheers...